# How is this even possible, that unrelated (and blatantly wrong) answer got 5 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

Please take a look at this questions answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5620517/77764

The answer is clearly wrong (**average month has 32 days**), but I can not understand, is this a joke or are there at least 5 people who looked at it and thought "Yeah, that is a good answer with reasoning and explanation".

I have flagged the answer for deletion with a comment along the lines of "not an actual answer, just a curious loosely related joke?" Which is perfectly fitting with an existing close reason "**It is not an answer**. This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."

The reason I post here, is that the person who gave that answer believes it is correct and asks for moderators intervention ("This and your other answer shows me you aren't serious at all or I'm wrong with alpha shapes. I think this deserve some attention from mods").

Can you help us clear this out please?

Comment: Not judging if the particular answer is correct or not - Don't flag wrong answers. Downvote them. And if you have the priviledge vote to delete.

Comment: @juergend: It appeared to me that this answer perfectly fits the flag "It is not an answer. This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." As you can see, the answer is not strictly "wrong" it's just unrelated.

Comment: *"not an actual answer, just a curious loosely related joke?"* It is an actual answer, and I'm hard pressed to believe a moderator would interfere. Downvote and move on if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @KromStern: **It is still an attempt at answering**. The 'not an answer' flag is *strictly* only for posts that are not attempts at answering the question. Think 'Thanks, this worked for me', or 'Did you solve this problem? I have it too!' or 'Falderalderal, I am so trolling you with nonsense' posts.

Comment: @Bart: Can I post "Month has 40 days because I read about Mars orbit at NASA"? ;)

Comment: You can do anything you put your mind to @KromStern. I believe in you.

Comment: @Bart, MartijnPieters: Thanks for your participation, I appreciate that you don't silently downvote and help me to get SO better. So "The average amount of days in a month is 32 because when you construct a calendar using a space-filling-curve the calendar fills always a grid of power of 2" is a valid answer, but not very correct one, am I getting you right?

Comment: @KromStern: Yes, it's still an answer. It addresses what the question is about. Sure, it implicitly ridicules the question, and thus, in my eyes, deserves to be downvoted, but it is still, in terms of the Stack Exchange model, an answer.

Comment: I'm not here to judge its correctness. However, the OP seems to be genuinely attempting to answer. In such a case, flagging it is no good. We have downvotes for incorrect answers (assuming it is one) and moderators don't need to be involved there.

Comment: Why is no one talking about how blatantly off topic the question is? My delete vote is in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll sum up in a wiki-answer:

*Yes, it's still an answer. It addresses what the question is about. Sure, it implicitly ridicules the question, and thus, in my eyes, deserves to be downvoted, but it is still, in terms of the Stack Exchange model, an answer. –  Martijn Pieters*

*I'm not here to judge its correctness. However, the OP seems to be genuinely attempting to answer. In such a case, flagging it is no good. We have downvotes for incorrect answers (assuming it is one) and moderators don't need to be involved there. - Bart*

That means I can too post that "Average month has 40 days because I read about Mars orbit at NASA and Earth is round too, given AlBouquerce equation of celestial bodies [link]". That would be an attempt to answer, not very good one, but perfectly legal for SO format, where good answers get upvotes and bad answers get ignored or downvoted.

Comment: Personaly I think a good answer is deleted. Although wrong (32 days) it has a good proof!

Comment: Perhaps you got the "proof" wrong. There's no statement on the linked page, that a year perfectly fits into a 32x32 table. What is said there, is that to fit a year onto a square power-of-two table, the table needs to be big enough (2^5 x 2^5). And there remains extra space that can be filled with following year and a part.

Comment: Also I think 32 days is not perfectly wrong. It's not only about month and so on the calendar shows the weeks and months not just like a list but also in this quads.

Comment: There was a comment in my answer saying in finance it's 32 days in the month!!!!

Comment: @Phpdna no there isn't, and it's not.

Comment: @David:It seems so:http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3554/does-one-months-notice-period-mean-30-or-31-days

Comment: I can not see such fact on the linked page, could you point at it please?

Comment: Can you read? The one day is free.. Also comment is deleted.